# How to remove multiple mediaelement.js players?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I need to 'manually' remove multiple mediaelement.js players from a page.

**I've tried:**

```
video_player_1.remove(); 
video_player_2.remove();
video_player_3.remove();
...
```

(And tried the above in various looping ways to try to remove all the players.)

**And :**

```
if (mejs) {
    var players = Object.keys(mejs.players);
    players.forEach( function(player) {
        mejs.players[player].remove();
    });
}
```

**And:**

```
mejs.players = {};
```

**And even:**

```
mejs = {};
```

Nothing seems to *fully* remove the players and any events associated with them. When I navigate back to the videos page I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'video_player_1.addEventListener')
```

Has anyone else run into this and found a solution? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
I should note that I add the following listeners to each player when it's created:

```
video_player_1.addEventListener('ended', function(event) {
    //Code that advances to the next video here ...
}
```

Comment: Try removing the element from DOM and set that player variable to null

Comment: Hi @Hardy, I am doing that. The 'page' that contains the videos is loaded in via $.load() and removed using $.empty() (which also removes the elements from the DOM).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), this works fine:

```
var player = $('#player')[0].player;
player.remove();
```

Building on that, this should remove all instances of mejs on your video elements:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mejs_players = new Array();
        var player;
        $('video').each(function() {
            player = $(this)[0].player;
            player.remove();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested the latest code, the remove function should change to

```
$('video').each(function() {
        player = $(this).data("mediaelementplayer");
        alert(player);
        player.remove();
    });
```